# Opening CMD app on Android

Tags: terminal

I have got a software that I use on my pc, it is some kind of console that runs on CMD. Can I port or open the software in my phone? The file extension in the software is .exe but once I open it it opens Command Prompt, so I believe its a CMD app. Can Terminal Emulator open it? If so how do I do it?

Comment: You can't run exe files on Android.  They're Windows executables, just like the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

exe files are Windows executable files. They can be executed only on Windows OS. You can't run exe even on a Windows phone.

Only apk (Android Package) files can be installed in Android phones.

If you want to run a terminal (Command Prompt) on Android, install [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)

Even then, only Linux commands can be executed on the Terminal Emulator. You can't execute Windows Commands.